# Tracking different language web domains on Google Analytics (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-4

I've a website and I've different domains for each language site.

For example, I have, https://www.example.com

I also have https://in.example.com and also https://br.example.com

Currently, my GA4 property(set up by another colleague) seems to be capturing data for all of them together.

On Google Data studio, I can see this when I try to use the "Full page URL" column and see views corresponding to in, uk and

I'm unsure how this works and was wondering what the best way of tracking different domains would be.

Editing to make it clearer. The problem I faced was that I was using the pre-created dashboards on Google Analytics. The answer here helps me with what I need, i.e. using the hostname and the page path dimensions to get data for different hostnames separately

Comment: This seems like a question much better suited to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yes, you already have the hit-level `hostname` dimension that allows you to distinguish between the subdomains. `Full UTL` should do the trick too.

Using a custom dimension for this is unwise since their number is limited.

You indicate that there's a problem, but don't actually describe it. If you want to be sure that all data is captured correctly, you need to go to the site and inspect the network requests its pages send to Google's `collect` endpoint. You want to look at the `dl` field there and make sure that it reflects the full url properly. I actually wouldn't suggest doing it unless there are indicators in data that something's wrong since `dl` is always equal to `window.location.href` by default and is rarely overriden.

Comment: Thanks @BNazaruk for this answer.

It's not a problem per se, but I just wanted to know if that is the best way to capture it. For example, on the google analytics dashboard, when I see data for a page path that is "/home", does that include data from https://in.example.com/home and https://www.example.com/home or both. And what would be the best way to actually capture this information.

Comment: First of all, you don't use pre-built reports in GA4. They're bugged. You want to use the Explorer. In the Explorer, you can use multiple dimensions. Have your page path dimension indicating /home and add the hostname dimension indicating the subdomain. You'll see everything there.

Comment: This is super cool, thanks a lot, @BNazaruk. Appreciate the help with this! Also, if you have any resources other than official google documentation that you find helpful, could you kindly share?